# How to record video and upload to server using Android?

Tags: android, video, file-upload

I am making an Android app where the user will record a short video and when they are done recording, the video automatically uploads to a server. I found a tutorial that does exactly what I want, but with pictures instead of video. Would I do it the same way for video or how can I change the code in the tutorial to make it for video instead of pictures?

Tutorial link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tEiiUOLemA

Comment: This feed might be for you
[android-capture-video-and-upload-it-to-server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259799/android-capture-video-and-upload-it-to-server-using-single-button)

Comment: I was looking at it and it looked very familiar. It is a tutorial on youtube and it seems like most of the code is deprecated. I hadn't seen this post. I will try tutorial again and see if that question helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code to successfully upload video from Android to a web server.

Note there are several alternatives libraries for HTTP communication in Android - for video you need to make sure whatever one you choose, if you don't want to use the one below, supports Multipart messages. A good overview of HTTP in Android is here: https://packetzoom.com/blog/which-android-http-library-to-use.html

```js
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class VideoUploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {
    /* This Class is an AsynchTask to upload a video to a server on a background thread
     * 
     */

    private VideoUploadTaskListener thisTaskListener;
    private String serverURL;
    private String videoPath;

    public VideoUploadTask(VideoUploadTaskListener ourListener) {
        //Constructor
        Log.d("VideoUploadTask","constructor");

        //Set the listener
        thisTaskListener = ourListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Upload the video in the background
        Log.d("VideoUploadTask","doInBackground");

        //Get the Server URL and the local video path from the parameters
        if (params.length == 2) {
            serverURL = params[0];
            videoPath = params[1];
        } else {
            //One or all of the params are not present - log an error and return
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","One or all of the params are not present");
            return -1;
        }


        //Create a new Multipart HTTP request to upload the video
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(serverURL);

        //Create a Multipart entity and add the parts to it
        try {
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","Building the request for file: " + videoPath);
            FileBody filebodyVideo = new FileBody(new File(videoPath));
            StringBody title = new StringBody("Filename:" + videoPath);
            StringBody description = new StringBody("Test Video");
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            reqEntity.addPart("videoFile", filebodyVideo);
            reqEntity.addPart("title", title);
            reqEntity.addPart("description", description);
            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            //Log the error
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","UnsupportedEncodingException error when setting StringBody for title or description");
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }

        //Send the request to the server
        HttpResponse serverResponse = null;
        try {
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","Sending the Request");
            serverResponse = httpclient.execute( httppost );
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //Log the error
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","ClientProtocolException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log the error
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","IOException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Check the response code
        Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","Checking the response code");
        if (serverResponse != null) {
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","ServerRespone" + serverResponse.getStatusLine());
            HttpEntity responseEntity = serverResponse.getEntity( );
            if (responseEntity != null) {
                //log the response code and consume the content
                Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","responseEntity is not null");
                try {
                    responseEntity.consumeContent( );
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //Log the (further...) error...
                    Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","IOexception consuming content");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
        } else {
            //Log that response code was null
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","serverResponse = null");
            return -1;
        }

        //Shut down the connection manager
        httpclient.getConnectionManager( ).shutdown( ); 
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        //Check the return code and update the listener
        Log.d("VideoUploadTask onPostExecute","updating listener after execution");
        thisTaskListener.onUploadFinished(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: how and from where are you getting params[0] and params[1] values?

Comment: They are passed in as parameters from whatever invokes the task. They will be different depending on the server you want to upload to and the place the video is on your device.

Answer (score 0):

[This is](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/) the better tutorial to for implementing this feature in app. But file// scheme is now not allowed after API level 24. So for that you need to [look here](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en)
,I hope by this 2 links you will easily implement this.

Comment: I used the tutorial and now I have the app and server running. Although it says upload is successful, but I don't see the file uploaded. Is it bc of the file// scheme issue?

Comment: Actually, it uploads. But only if the file size is small!